# Sounds from bundle still there after app update

Tags: ios, file, bundle

I have a list of sounds in my app main bundle, which are displayed in a list in the app.

I decided to delete some of the bundle, and they're 100% removed from the bundle/folder. I can't find them anywhre on disk. But when I compile over my old app version, they're still available in the actual app.

My only solution for testing is to re-install from a fresh install and not an update, but this is clearly not a viable solution for AppStore users.

My problem is that it is very likely that I will add/remove files and submit updates in the appstore, but I don't want  to have file conflicts.

What should I do to have my files actually removed from the app when I removed them from the bundle?

Comment: Have you cleaned your project after you've deleted those files before building it again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Technote 2285](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2285/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011323):

> Xcode's app install process is optimized for development, but is slightly different than how iTunes and the App Store install apps. This is good during development because it's faster, but using Xcode to install an app over an older old build may create a "frankenbuild" with legacy files inside the .app bundle that won't exist after an App Store update.
>
> When an app is updated, the old .app bundle is completely replaced, and all data in the old app container may be preserved as well.

Installing with Xcode will just copy all files inside the app bundle to the old install location. Files copied during an installation of a previous version of the app bundle are still there.

Installing with iTunes or App Store will create a new install location and only copy the files in the current version of the app bundle. Files that existed in a previous version of the app bundle are not available.

The data in the app container, e.g. user documents, are not changed.

Comment: The first paragraph leaves me to believe that  everything will be gone, the last one makes me doubt.
I am not doing anything to saves files from the old bundle, that means that I will indeed ONLY have the new-bundle files, am I right to believe that?

Comment: I added an explanation of the tech note.

Comment: Would you please elaborate some more on what they mean by "app container". For example: Does every app have an app container? Can an app have more than one app container? Is the app container a directory? Where is the app container located in the device's file system? What data does the app container contain initially, ie, by default? What are all the ways that data in the app container are created, modified, or deleted?